# Flask SocketIO in GCP Cloud Run experiencing issues with pub/sub using GCP Redis after a certain period of time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, flask-socketio, vpc, google-vpc

We are currently running Flask SocketIO in GCP Cloud Run, with message_queue utilizing GCP Redis (Memorystore) through a VPC network.

The GCP Redis instance is of Basic type, with a capacity of 12 GB.
Our VPC network comprises 2 min instances, 3 max instances, with 3 active instances, and other servers that use the same VPC network.
We are using Flask SocketIO version 5.3.2
We are using python package `redis` version 4.4.0

Initially, everything was functioning properly, but we have encountered issues after a certain period of time. The first instance happened after approximately 10 hours, and the second instance occurred after about 3 days. (Note that the revisions we were using were different between instances)

We have observed the following:

- The first time, we added some log and re-deployed the Flask SocketIO server, and it started working properly again.
- The second time:

  1. We switched to the previous revision (1) of Flask SocketIO server, and it started working properly again.
  2. We switched back to the newest revision (2), and it stopped working.
  3. We switched back to the previous revision (1) again, and it started working properly again.
  4. However, after a while, when we switched back to the newest revision (2), it started working again.

We checked the GCP logging explorer, around the last time the browser was able to receive websocket data, and found an error log: `ERROR:socketio:Cannot publish to Redis... retrying`

We didn't see `Cannot publish to Redis... giving up`

When the server stopped working, the log from Flask SocketIO (also Python-SocketIO and Python-EngineIO that it uses) only showed `emitting event "message" to room_1 [/some-namespace]`, which is from Python-SocketIO.

In the logs from Python-SocketIO, there was no `pubsub message: emit` found, which is generated when it receives a message from Redis in the _thread function of the PubSubManager class.

(If more information is needed, please let me know)

Comment: You make a reference to a "previous" revision and a "newest" revision. What does that mean? Is this different versions of your Python packages or something else?

Comment: Revisions means different deployments on GCP (Google Cloud Platform).

When switch to the "previous" version, GCP will start a new server to run it.
I guess when the "previous" version is running, the old one was not killed, so when I switch back to the "newest" version, the server still can't send socket data to clients.

Comment: b.t.w. I also post this related discussion:
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/discussions/1115